# devtools::load_all() but not h2o please

Tags: r, h2o, devtools

Recently I started working with the h2o package in R-Studio. But now I have a different problem: everytime I try to `load_all()` my own project package, which has absolutely nothing to do with h2o, it initiates h2o without me saying. This causes different problems with functions that are masked by h2o.

```
> devtools::load_all()

ℹ Loading my_own_package
 Connection successful!

R is connected to the H2O cluster: 
    H2O cluster uptime:        blabla 
    H2O cluster timezone:       blabla 
    H2O data parsing timezone:  blabla
    H2O cluster version:        blabla
    H2O cluster version age:    blabla 
    H2O cluster name:           blabla
    H2O cluster total nodes:    blabla
    H2O cluster total memory:   blabla
    H2O cluster total cores:    blabla 
    H2O cluster allowed cores:  blabla
    H2O cluster healthy:        blabla
    H2O Connection ip:          blabla
    H2O Connection port:        blabla
    H2O Connection proxy:       blabla
    H2O Internal Security:      blabla
    R Version:                  blabla 

Error in UseMethod("mutate") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "function"
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

Is there a way such that I can `devtools::load_all()` my own package but not load h2o?

Comment: Why not use `library("myPackage")`?

Comment: what happens when you use `load_code(path = ".", quiet = NULL)` when you are in your package environment? If this loads h2o, there is on R script in your R directory that calls h2o. `load_code` is part of what happens when you use `load_all`. Also check all your warnings.

Comment: @phiver bingo! I double checked my directory and indeed there was a hidden file that calls the h2o library! I removed it and now `devtools::load_all()` works as it should! Thank you